# linq query to get possible combinations

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have table1 like

| funid | reasonid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

and users table(users will repeat) like below

| userid | reasonid |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 3 |
| 13 | 1 |
| 13 | 3 |

how to write a query to get the users satisfying table 1 combination {1,2} and {1,3}, so as per the above data userid 10 and 13 should be the output because user should have combination of {1,2} OR {1,3}

Thanks

Comment: What's the sql tag for?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, I don't think userid 13 would be selected. There is no row in table 1 where funid=1 and reasonid=3. Therefore, the first table would only return the row where funid=1 and reasonid=2, then querying the user's table, you would only query where reasonid=2 and get only userid 10. Since you do expect to also get userid 13, please clarify exactly how you would get it.

Comment: @EricJ.As I understand it, you can think of funid as a rule ID. Rule 1 requires reasons 1 and 2 to be present, rule 2 requires reasons 1 and 3 to be present. Userid 13 satisfies rule 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first count the number or reasons per funid in table1 , and then compare that with the count (distinct reasonid) obtained with a join between table1 and users grouped by userid and funid. If the counts are equal, then that user satisfies the condition.

Something like:

```
SELECT B.userid, B.funid
FROM (
    SELECT funid, reasonCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY funid
) A
JOIN (
    SELECT U.userid, T.funid, reasonCount = COUNT(DISTINCT U.reasonid)
    FROM users U
    JOIN table1 T ON T.reasonid = U.reasonid
    GROUP BY U.userid, T.funid
) B ON B.funid = A.funId AND B.reasonCount = A.reasonCount
ORDER BY B.userid, B.funid
```

The COUNT(DISTINCT ...) is only needed if it is possible that a user could reference the same reason more than once. You can drop the funid and add distinct to the final result to eliminate dups caused by users who satisfy more than one rule set (such as a user referencing reasons 1, 2, and 3).

Results:

| userid | funid |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 13 | 2 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=188f15f3babbff3bc3612204631c9f84) for a demo.

Comment: Oops. Missed the "linq" part of the question, so this is not the answer. I wil leave it up anyway as a demonstration of concept..

Answer (score 1):

```
(int funid, int reasonid)[] t1 = new[] { (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3) };
(int userid, int reasonid)[] t2 = new[] { (10, 1), (10, 2), (11, 1), (12, 3), (13, 1), (13, 3) };
var rules = from x in t1 group x by x.funid into g 
            select (rule: g.Key, reasons: g.Select(x => x.reasonid));
var users = from x in t2 group x by x.userid into g 
            select (user: g.Key, reasons: g.Select(x => x.reasonid));
var result = from r in rules from u in users 
             where r.reasons.SequenceEqual(u.reasons) 
             select (r.rule, u.user);
```

result is { (1, 10), (2, 13) }

Comment: I'm facing error like ienumerable doesn't contain definition for sequenceequal and I'm preparing my rules and users from database table

Comment: To accommodate ordering, potential dups, and superset conditions, I suggest something like `where r.reasons.All(r => u.reasons.contains(r))` as an alternative. Whether this is desired or not depends on whether a user with reasons {3, 2, 1, 4, 1} should match both rules {1,2} and {1,3} or neither. `where r.reasons.Except(u.reasons).Any()` might work also.

Comment: Correction to my prior comment - I mistakenly omitted a not operator in `where !r.reasons.Except(u.reasons).Any()`